# Aligning a character to the top of adjacent letters

Tags: html, css, typography

I wish to align a character in HTML to the tops of the characters next to it.  The css vertical-align attribute seems to be what I want, but I'm having some trouble.

Using `vertical-align: text-top` doesn't seem to do what I want, but I thought it should from reading the spec.

Currently, I'm using `vertical-align: 10%` which is a reasonable solution, except that I have to calculate the proper number on each platform to get it to look right. Browser detecting to set the value to one that I think is probably right seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: After a few experiments, I don't think there is a way to do this without checking the actual rendered font because the area above the lower-case c is considered part of the character's "space", if that makes any sense. You could make it an upper-case C and then shrink it.

Comment: Yeah, it’s all very dependent on the font itself, and the font rendering in each browser/operating system. You can’t reliably do precise typography in HTML on the web, as the web assumes a worldwide-scale variety of client software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly, but you could use table cells.

First define some styles:

```
.bigletter
{
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:20px;
}
.upletter
{
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:14px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.downletter
{
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:14px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Then the html:

```
<tr>
  <td class='bigletter'>M</td>
  <td class='upletter'>C</td>
  <td class='bigletter'>P</td>
  <td class='downletter'>hexxx</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the `<sup>` tag. It's meant for exacly what you're trying to do. After you implement it, you can control it even more with css.

Example: `M<sup>c</sup>Phe` yeilds M<sup>c</sup>Phe

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_sup.asp

If the "c" is too small, just do `<style> sup { font-size: 9pt } </style>` or something like that.

Comment: `<sup>` aligns it above the top of the text, which isn't what I want either.

Comment: @McPherrin You can adjust that with `padding`

Answer (score 2):

Some of these ideas are on the right track, but none quite work.  I ended up combining Josh Stodola's suggestion to use `text-transform: uppercase;` with Keltex's suggestion to use a capital letter in a smaller font to have pseudo-small-caps, even if using tables is unnessicary.

It still relies on futzing around with font sizes and line heights, but I can get a more consistent effect this way at least.

The suggestion to use `<sup>` isn't really helpful, as I'd have to override all its styles anyways, so it doesn't differ from a `<span>`.  Semantically there may be a difference, but small enough that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Anthony's comment to the question gave me an idea to wrap the "c" with a semantically correct `<sup>` tag (or I guess you could continue to use a `<span>`) and then use the CSS `text-transform: uppercase;` on it.